# Plotly Plot surface 3D not displayed

Tags: python, plotly, surface

I really can't find an answer on the forum. I want to create a 3d surface with plotly offline. I use sample points. The scene displays empty without a surface. Please help, thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()
df3=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y':[10,20,30,20,10], 'z':[5,4,3,2,1]})

trace0= Surface(x=df3['x'], y=df3['y'], z=df3['z'])
data=[trace0]
fig=dict(data=data)
plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is you haven't defined a surface of data, since your `z` data is just one-dimensional. For example, this should show a surface:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

df3=pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'y':[10,20,30,20,10],
    'z':[[5,4,3,2,1]] * 5
})

trace0= Surface(x=df3['x'], y=df3['y'], z=df3['z'])
data=[trace0]
fig=dict(data=data)
plot(fig)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this... if I am looking at a 2D Gaussian distribution in particular.... shouldn't I have a single z for each x,y?

Comment: Yes. The above `z` is like a 2D matrix. Note that in Python if `a = [[1, 2]]`, then `a * 2` will be `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]`. So this was just a trivial example to demonstrate the form of the required data.