# 3D surface plot never shows any data

Tags: python, plotly

The 3D surface plot in plotly never shows the data, I get the plot to show up, but nothing shows up in the plot, as if I had ploted an empty Data Frame.

At first, I tried something like the solution I found here([Plotly Plot surface 3D not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966097/plotly-plot-surface-3d-not-displayed)), but had the same result, another plot with no data.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'y':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],'z': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]})
iplot(dict(data=[Surface(x=df3['x'], y=df3['y'], z=df3['z'])]))
```

And so I tried the code at the plotly website(the first cell of this notebook: https://plot.ly/python/3d-scatter-plots/), exactly as it is there, just to see if their example worked, but I get an error.

I am getting this:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/sOxRsIDLVkBGKTksUfVqm3HtaSQAN_ybQq2HLA-aclzEU-9ekmvd1ETdfsswC2SdbysizOI=s151

But I should get this:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5Hy2Z-97_vwd3ftKBA6dYZfikJHnA-UMEjd3PHvEvdBzw2m2zeEHBtneLC1jzO3RmE2lyw=s151

Observation: could not post the images because of lack of reputation.

Comment: which `iplot` are you using? are you in a notebook environment?

Answer (score 2):

In order to plot a surface you have to provide a value for each point. In this case your `x` and `y` are series of size `5`, that means that your `z` should have a shape `(5, 5)`.

If I had a bit more info I could give you more details but for a minimal working example try to pass a `(5, 5)` dataframe, numpy array or even a list of lists to the `z` value of data.

**EDIT:**

In a notebook environment the following code works for me:

```
from plotly import offline
from plotly import graph_objs as go
offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

df3 = {'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'y':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],'z': [[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]*5}
offline.iplot(dict(data=[go.Surface(x=df3['x'], y=df3['y'], z=df3['z'])]))
```

as shown here:

[image]

I'm using plotly 3.7.0.

Comment: Even if z has a (5, 5) shape it still outputs an empty graphic:


`df3 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'y':[10, 20, 30, 20, 10],'z': [[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]] * 5})
iplot(dict(data=[Surface(x=df3['x'], y=df3['y'], z=df3['z'])]))`


I have also attempted to create a separate z variable to use in the plot:


`df3 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'y':[10, 20, 30, 20, 10],'z': [[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]] * 5})
z = [[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]] * 5
iplot(dict(data=[Surface(x=df3['x'], y=df3['y'], z=z)]))`


I also tried to use many other types of data for the variable z, such as numpy arrays, Series.

Comment: And yes I am in a note book enviroment.

Comment: Edited with a notebook code version, if it still doesn't work it must be something in the installation, try reinstalling plotly or something similar.